# Updating state causing tests to not stop

Tags: javascript

I have a React application. I am using Jest and React Testing library for unit testing.

I have to test a component. In the useEffect of the component, there is an API call made and once the response is received, we update the component's local state.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({})

useEffect(()=>{
  // Make API call to a custom fetch hook
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
  setData(response.data) //response data is a JSON object
},[response])
```

The test files code snippet is as below -

```
const {getByTestId} = render(<MyComponent></MyComponent>)
```

I have not put any assertions yet because of the inifinite running test cases

What have I done? I have been able to mock the fetch call and execute setData.

The problem - The tests keep running forever. But if I change the response.data to some boolean or string or number, the tests do not run infinitly.
Also, if I put a dummy object in the initialization of the state, the tests run fine.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  name: 'Test',
  Age: '99'
})
```

Comment: Please paste more code and the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an object as dependency in `useEffect` is not a good idea, since even if the data in object remains same, on every render -- object reference changes - the effect will run again (even if the data within stays same).

> A workaround for this would be stringifying the dependency with JSON.stringify. (although doing on data containing some objects like dates, symbols, null or undefined etc. isn't recommended)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setData(response.data)
}, [JSON.stringify(response)]);
```

> Doing above shouldn't affect your UI.

Other solution would be to store the previous value of response and compare before you do `setData`. You can use `usePrevious` hook:

```js
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

Comment: You are right! But first question. The useEffect was indeed running twice in Unit test (which was causing the issue), but in the application, it ran just once. Why do you think so? Second question - since useEffect ran twice, why did the tests run infinitely?

Comment: My first guess is, your test environment is different that the browsers so events and change detection might be different.

Comment: You can debug this using a custom hook "useLastUpdate". It detects which prop changes cause the render. The gist for this is available here - https://gist.github.com/pritam-patil/26069bab28228dc61dbaa19b13d300bf